# Ошибка индекса: Индекс списка вне диапазона C#

Tags: c#, массивы, вконтакте, объекты, index

```
    public void TheAnswerToKeyword(int index)
    {
        var target = targets[index];
        var fs = new FlooderSettings();

        if (fs.GetHistory(target, token) != "Ок")
        {
            dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(fs.GetHistory(target, token));
            var text = Convert.ToString(json["response"]["items"][0]["text"]);
```

Comment: Ок, где то среди этого довольно большого участка кода возникла какая то ошибка. Что вы ожидаете от того, кто прочитает ваш вопрос? На какую помощь вы расчитываете?

Comment: @tym32167 поправил и выделил участок кода , где возникает предполагаемая ошибка

Comment: Так в какой строке ошибка? Либо на `targets[index]` ошибка, либо на `json["response"]["items"][0]`

Comment: [Отладка кода в C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 1):

В C# Массивы имеют нижнюю и верхнюю границы. Нативно поддерживается нижняя граница в `0`, верхняя задаётся программистом.

Пример:

```cs
var arr = new int[3];
```

Нижняя  граница – 0, верхняя граница – 3. Количество элементов в массиве равно их разнице, т. е. 3-м. Индекс в данном случае может принимать значения в вот таком `[0; 3)` диапазоне. Если, в данном случае, будет выполняться данное условие для индекса `index`: `index < 0 && index >= 3`, то данный индекс будет считаться не действительным, т. к. выходит за границы массива.

<sup>Memory dump</sup>

```pascal
        ↓            Границы массива           ↓
┌───┬───╥────────────┬────────────┬────────────╥───┬───┐
│ … │ … ║ Элемент #0 │ Элемент #1 │ Элемент #2 ║ … │ … │
└───┴───╨────────────┴────────────┴────────────╨───┴───┘
```

Исходя из вышесказанного, просто держите у себя в голове, что это выдаст ошибки run-time'а:

```
var arr = new int[3];
_ = arr[3]; // ошибка `IndexOutOfRangeException`
```

---

У вас 2 потенциально опасных места:

- `targets[index]`
- `json["response"]["items"][0]`

В 1-м случае мы не знаем размер массива и сам индекс, следовательно, вам нужно просто запустить вашу программу в режиме отладки ([отладка в VS](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019), [отладка в VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)) и узнать необходимые значения – дальше действуйте по ситуации.

Во 2-м случае вы, скорее всего, обращаетесь в массиву JSON. Раз вы не смогли обратиться к элементу под индексом `0`, зн. границы массива выглядят так: `[0; 0)`, т. е. `Ø`, т. е. ваш массив пустой. Проверьте во время той же отладки ваш JSON документ/фрагмент: возможно, массив, к которому вы обращаетесь, пустой.

Таким образом панацеей для таких ошибок является отладка – используйте, не пожалеете.